# Graph that shows bounce rate overlaid with the organic traffic per day in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, traffic, bounce-rate

I'm trying to review the bounce-rate of a site after it's been launched, to do so I'm trying to get a graph that shows the bounce-rate overlaid with with the organic traffic per day in Google Analytics, but can't seem to get it set it up - any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Analytics: Acquisition > Channels click on "Organic Search" - this gives the report with the evolution of organic traffic.
On the top of this graph you see Sessions vs (Select a Metric) - click on the (Select a Metric) and start typing "Bounce rate" in the search field - select when the field appears.
This should be the graph you're looking for.